# Is this sufficient to run a step-down buck converter (SBC) safely?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to steal power from a 12 V, 2 A DC power supply that drives a monitor I have lying around to also run a Raspberry Pi 3 A+. I'm using a [MP1584EN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MQGMOKI) step-down buck converter (SBC) to drop the voltage to 5.0 V and driving the Pi directly off the output via the GPIO headers.

Is this going to be clean enough to safely drive the computer long term? I would like to replace the pot with a fixed value, but first things first.

I know I may run into an amperage issue, but with my bench DC supply it should only pull around 0.12 amps so it's worth a shot.

Comment: It's worth a shot.

Comment: First up, where did you get the acronym of 'SBC' to mean 'step-down buck converter'? I think for most of us, 'SBC' in this context would be 'single board computer'. Would the output be 'clean' enough? We've got no specs to make a clear determination, but I would expect it would be ok. On the RPi, the 5V gets converted to a number of voltages by its pmic. I suspect you might be pushing your luck with only a 12V 0.12A power source. The RPi probably wants over an Amp at 5V so that translates to around 0.5A at 12V (accounting for losses).

Comment: @Kartman Also, a step-up buck converter is impossible so specifying it as a step-down buck converter is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine, most regulated switched mode power modules poeduce well regulated output. an MP1484 based moudule ("Mini360") works fine here, I have not tried an MP1584 module, but I would expect similar performance.